# React componentDidMount does not fire

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component like a function with componentDidMount event. But it is not triggered at all.

```
function ItemsList() {

    return (
        <div>This is Items List component</div>
    )

    function componentDidMount(  )
    {
        alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me please what  is the problem with this pattern?

Comment: Please read the official docs about class and functional components: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: `componentDidMount` and similar lifecycle methods are methods of the `React.Component` class, that you can override inside your own class components (these inherit from it). But you don't have a class, you just have a function called `componentDidMount` nested inside a function - React attaches no special meaning to that. If you want to use the equivalent inside a function component you are looking for the `useEffect` Hook.

Answer (score 1):

Functional components do not have lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`.
You can imitate the lifecycle behaviour of `componentDidMount` with the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
        alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
}, [])
```